# How to normalize adjacent <i> tags within a <p> tag

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to write an algorithm to normalize the children of a "p" tag

```
<p><i>this text</i> <i>is italic</i></p>
```

with the expected result

```
<p><i>this text is italic</i></p>
```

The algorithm I wrote is:

```
def add_style_to_spaces_between_tags(card_text)
    doc = Nokogiri.HTML(card_text)
    add_char = ""
    # Iterate on all nodes within p tags
    doc.search('p').children.each do |child|
      if add_char != ""
        first_text_node = find_first_text_node(child)
        if first_text_node.present?
          first_text_node.content = add_char + first_text_node.content
          add_char = ""
        end
        next
      end
      #if the node is a space or a nbsp
      if child.text == " " || child.text == 160.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
        prev_node = child.previous.name
        next_node = child.next.name
        # Only if the the surrounding nodes to space/nbsp are matching and the previous is not a br tag
        # then set the add_char flag to move the space/nbsp to the next node
        if prev_node != 'br' && prev_node == next_node
          case(child.text)
            when " "
             add_char = child.content
            when 160.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
             add_char = 160.chr(Encoding::UTF_8)
            end
          child.remove
        end
      end
    end
    doc.search('p').each do |p_node|
      doc = merge_text_nodes(p_node)
    end
    card_text = doc.inner_html
    card_text
  end
    
  def find_first_text_node(node)
    result = nil
    node.search('.//text()').each { |t|
      if t.content.length > 0
        result = t
        break
      end
    }
    result
  end

  def merge_text_nodes(node)
    puts 'text node'
    puts node
    prev_is_text = false

    newnodes = []
    node.children.each do |element|
      if element.text?
        if prev_is_text
          newnodes[-1].content += element.text
        else
          newnodes << element
        end
        element.remove
        prev_is_text = true
      else
        newnodes << merge_text_nodes(element)
        element.remove
        prev_is_text = false
      end
    end

    node.children.remove
    newnodes.each do |item|
      node.add_child(item)
    end

    return node
  end
```

but the output is:

```
<p><i>this text</i><i> is italic</i></p>
```

How can I get the desired output?

The Rspec unit test suite is:

```
describe "Italicize spaces between italics" do
    it "production case" do
      node = '<p><span tts:fontStyle="italic">der</span> <span tts:fontStyle="italic">Tri-Circle-D Ranch begrüßt:</span></p>'
      expect(helper.add_style_to_spaces_between_tags(node)).
          to eq('<p><span tts:fontstyle="italic">der Tri-Circle-D Ranch begrüßt:</span></p>')
      end
    it "production case with nbsp" do
      node = '<p><span tts:fontStyle="italic">der</span>&nbsp;<span tts:fontStyle="italic">Tri-Circle-D Ranch begrüßt:</span></p>'
      expect(helper.add_style_to_spaces_between_tags(node)).
          to eq("<p><span tts:fontstyle=\"italic\">der\u00A0Tri-Circle-D Ranch begrüßt:</span></p>")
    end
    it "space between 2 i tags" do
      node = '<p><i>this text</i> <i>is italic</i></p>'
      expect(helper.add_style_to_spaces_between_tags(node)).to eq('<p><i>this text is italic</i></p>')
      end
    it "non breaking space between 2 i tags" do
      node = '<p><i>this text</i>&nbsp;<i>is italic</i></p>'
      expect(helper.add_style_to_spaces_between_tags(node)).to eq("<p><i>this text\u00A0is italic</i></p>")
    end
    it "No space between 2 i tags" do
      node = '<p><i>this text</i><i>is italic</i></p>'
      expect(helper.add_style_to_spaces_between_tags(node)).to eq('<p><i>this textis italic</i></p>')
      end
    it "space between 2 i tags with br included before space" do
      node = '<p><i>this text</i><br> <i>is italic</i></p>'
      expect(helper.add_style_to_spaces_between_tags(node)).to eq('<p><i>this text</i><br> <i>is italic</i></p>')
      end
    it "non breaking space between 2 i tags with br included before nbsp" do
      node = '<p><i>this text</i><br>&nbsp;<i>is italic</i></p>'
      expect(helper.add_style_to_spaces_between_tags(node)).to eq("<p><i>this text</i><br>\u00A0<i>is italic</i></p>")
      end
    it "space between 2 i tags with br included after space" do
      node = '<p><i>this text</i> <br><i>is italic</i></p>'
      expect(helper.add_style_to_spaces_between_tags(node)).to eq('<p><i>this text</i> <br><i>is italic</i></p>')
      end
    it "non breaking space between 2 i tags with br included after nbsp" do
      node = '<p><i>this text</i>&nbsp;<br><i>is italic</i></p>'
      expect(helper.add_style_to_spaces_between_tags(node)).to eq("<p><i>this text</i>\u00A0<br><i>is italic</i></p>")
      end
    it "space between 2 i tags with br included before and after space" do
      node = '<p><i>this text</i> <br> <i>is italic</i></p>'
      expect(helper.add_style_to_spaces_between_tags(node)).to eq('<p><i>this text</i> <br> <i>is italic</i></p>')
      end
    it "non breaking space between 2 i tags with br included before and after nbsp" do
      node = '<p><i>this text</i>&nbsp;<br>&nbsp;<i>is italic</i></p>'
      expect(helper.add_style_to_spaces_between_tags(node)).to eq("<p><i>this text</i>\u00A0<br>\u00A0<i>is italic</i></p>")
      end
    it "space between 2 i tags with a nested u tag in the first i tag" do
      node = '<p><i><u>this text</u></i> <i>is italic</i></p>'
      expect(helper.add_style_to_spaces_between_tags(node)).to eq('<p><i><u>this text</u> is italic</i></p>')
    end       
  end
```

Comment: See https://medium.com/machine-words/yak-shaving-and-bikeshedding-e3052f51234a for the terms for this. Joining adjacent `<i>` tags is akin to worrying that the size of the dot on the proverbial "I" is perfect. HTML will render the same with or without that change, so I'd focus on other things.

Answer (score 0):

You're making it a lot harder than it needs to be:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML('<p><i>this text</i> <i>is italic</i></p>')
doc.search('p i+i').each do |pii|
  pii.parent.inner_html = '<i>' + pii.parent.text + '</i>'
end
```

Which results in:

```
doc.to_html
# => "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n" +
#    "<html><body><p><i>this text is italic</i></p></body></html>\n"
```

`'p i+i'` tells Nokogiri to find all `<p><i>...</i>...<i>...</i>` nodes. Once you have them, loop through them, pointing to the parent `<p>` node and grab the contained text and rewrap it with an `<i>` tag.

In your code, as soon as you used `children` you fell down the rabbit hole. Iterating the DOM is *almost never* the right solution. Rely on selectors and Nokogiri's methods. They're available for a reason.